# Which libraries will be included in a statically linked C program?

Tags: c, static-linking, c-standard-library

I have the following program:

```c
# include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it (dynamically linked) and used `ldd` on `a.out`. I saw:

```
linux-vdso.so.1
libc.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

- The first is a virtual shared object provided by the kernel.
- The second is a C standard library.
- The third is a dynamic linker.

I am not sure how the first and third are affected by static linking, and I wonder if the whole standard library is used, even if I only include one header from it.

If I statically link this program, will the resulting binary

- contain `linux-vdso.so.1`, even though it is provided by the kernel?
- contain the entire C standard library, even though I only included `<stdio.h>`?
- contain `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, even though it is used to run dynamically linked programs?

Comment: stdio.h Is a header file, the implementation is up to the compiler but if you do create a static linked library (I'm not sure about other OS/Compilers) on Microsoft's Visual Studio Compiler, the entire MSVCRT (Microsoft's Implementation of the C standard library) is linked to the binary and significantly increases the size of the binary.

Comment: None of those shared objects will be included if you compile a static executable. It's a whole lot of `libc.a` (~20%) which will be included verbatim, though. (not linked to, since it's a static, not a shared library). Just compile your program with `cc -static`, then explore it with `objdump` or `readelf`; `readelf -a | grep FILE` will tell you all the object files from the `libc.a` archive which have been included in your binary.

Comment: Notice that static executables are NOT really supported with the GNU Standard C Library (glibc; which you are using). Everything will fall apart and you will just create a kind of "fat" dynamic executable (a static executable which loads shared objects explicitly) as soon as you're using any resolver functions in your program. The linker will warn you about it.

Comment: As @UncleBilly said, just try, what stops you? -- Anyway, when linking a library statically, the linker will include those objects that are needed to resolve a reference. For example, if you just call `exit()` in your program, `printf()` will commonly not be included, even if the library contains it. It's all a matter of the granularity of the library's objects. -- And, if statically linking with Microsoft's compiler include so much, it looks to me as a problem of that library, not a general problem.

Comment: @Irelia I don't think that's true. Did you enable LTO?